# How to destroy a parallel timeline?

Tags: time-travel

In a world similar to ours, mankind has invented time traveling technology since hundreds of years ago. Initially, it was very costly and only conducted for scientific purposes but nowadays it's became a mundane technology that's limited by a  particularly scarce mineral for its fuel.

Time travel could only be done to the past because the future is yet to be determined. It's became public knowledge that any changes to the past would make a parallel timeline which is completely independent of the original one. Therefore, people could do time travel and take advantage of--or even abuse--it (given they could afford the fuel).

Time travel is forbidden by the World Government unless it's deemed necessary. There's no special force to enforce the rule but the police does regular checking against possibility of time travel abuse.

A growing and sufficiently-funded religious sect deemed the parallel timeline as an affront to the Creation.Therefore, they plan to destroy every one of those timelines.

The question is how does one destroy a parallel timeline?

Comment: Since time travel requires a lot of handwavium, answer depends only on the properties of your handwavium. Properties we don't know, obviously.

Comment: What is the connection between the handwavium and the parallel timeline's destruction?

Comment: Molot's point is that you are going to have to define how your timetravel works.  Handwavium is the catch-all term for stuff that is currently thought to be impossible, but an author felt the need to have it to drive a plot forward.  In other words, when you define your version of time travel, you define how a parallel timeline can be destroyed -- or you define time travel such that a parallel timeline cannot be destroyed.  It is 100% up to you and your particular approach to time travel.

Comment: Please add more detail on how time travel works, and/or what tech we have do destroy the other timelines.

Comment: I see. Guess I'll elaborate the time travel mechanism first.

Comment: @CortAmmon thanks. That's exactly what I was thinking. Sorry for not being around to explain earlier.

Comment: Religious hate mobs have NEVER come up with impressive new technologies because the dogmatic stupidity the propagate hinders invention. If the parallel universe destroying tech is already available using existing tech then they might manage.

Answer (score 1):

A parallel timeline is, in essence, **a universe**, so you have to destroy a whole universe by, for example, speeding up the big crunch or eliminating one of the four essential forces, like the Atomic Strong Force or the Gravity, in the whole universe. Don't ask me how.

Comment: If a parallel timeline is, in essence, a universe created using time travel, so why should destroying a universe be any more difficult than creating a universe?

Comment: The same reason is why it's easy for a person to fall down a hole but difficult to fly out of it. Even though the persons weighs the same both times and therefore need the same energy to move it's mass one direction or the other. The universe is rigged for one of them, so the other goes against the grain.

Comment: That's a plausible analogy, however, it's also plausible the universe could be rigged to do both. Better too for the OP's world if you can.